# Not able to understand the meaning of this code

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return, structure

I dont understand what the following code is doing

```
auto sgn = [&](int x) 
{
        if (x > 0) return 1;
        else return -1;
};
```

What is the role of ampersand here? Is it a pointer? And is this block a structure or something like that?

I came across this block of code in codeforces round 636 division 3 editorial.

Comment: The ampersand is redundant.:)

Comment: can you please explain what this code is doing ?

Comment: This is a declaration of a lambda expression that checks if the passed argument is greater than zero.

Comment: *I came across this block of code in codeforces round 636 division 3 editorial.* -- Lambda expressions are a large part of C++ 11 and beyond.  You should know what they are, as they are a basic part of the C++ language.

Comment: Oh I got it now thanks man

Comment: Yes Paul I will definitely study this part now , sad that I don't know .

Comment: @AKASHROY -- If you have only used pre C++11, it is understood why this is new.  Don't be ashamed -- there are a lot of pre C++11 programmers who are in the same situation as you are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "there are a lot of pre C++11 programmers who are in the same situation as you are" - but, given that C++11 is almost 10 years old, you'd think/hope they would have caught up by now..

Comment: Believe it or not, I have come across some C++ programmers who wouldn't know a lambda if it hit them between the eyes, unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&` here means that the lambda captures all variables by reference.

The lambda returns `1` or `-1` depending on the value of the argument `x`, so the capture really doesn't actually matter here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to know about the semicolon. It reminds me of structure where I used to put semicolon .

Comment: @AKASHROY that's the syntax for using the lambda expression. []() -> {};

Comment: @AKASHROY The semicolon just ends the assignment. What's unclear there?

Comment: I actually did not know about lambda expressions Jesper sorry for the question

Comment: Thanks LinuX Man for stating the syntax.